# pear package installation in CPanel

Tags: php, linux, hosting, cpanel

I am using some functionalities of PHP PEAR Package in my CakePHP application like `Mail`, `Image_Text` etc.

I took a linux hosting from godaddy. When I deployed my application to the server, it did not worked. How do I install PHP Pear package and its extensions on server?

Should I have to contact with support or I can do it at my end?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server with cPanel/WHM with Go Daddy you can add Pear via EasyApache.

1. Log in to WHM as the 'root' user.
2. In the Find box type easy.
3. Click EasyApache (Apache Update).
4. Leave default, and then click Start customizing based on profile.
5. Leave default, and then click Next Step.
6. Leave default, and then click Next Step.
7. Leave default, and then click Next Step.
8. Click Exhaustive Options List.
9. Click pear, and then click Save and build.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install pear to begin with. SSH access will be required otherwise you will need to contact your host to install it for you. cPanel runs on CentOS and there are plenty of tutorials online to install Pear on CentOS. e.g. "yum install pear".

It will probably also be helpful to have access to WHM. (cPanels account controller).

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/PhpPearPackages